# How to make hyperlinks on HTML and R more efficient?

Tags: html, css, r

This is currently my HTML code that involves R:

```
<html>

  <style>
 
  .myDiv {
  border: 5px outset black;
  background-color: white;    
  text-align: center;
  }
 
  </style>

  <div class="myDiv">

  <h2>Image for Date</h2>
  
  <p>`r entire_date[3]`</p>
  
  <img src=`r test_url[3]` style="width:400px"> <br>
  
  <a href=`r test_url[1]`>Link 1 - .tif</a><br>
  <a href=`r test_url[2]`>Link 2 - .RDS</a><br>
  <a href=`r test_url[3]`>Link 3 - .png</a><br>
 
  </div>

</html>
```

where test_url is the directory of each and every file that I stored as a variable in R.

Does anyone know how I can create links to files more efficiently? I have a data frame that has 10000+ directories to files and each of them has 3 or 4 different type of image files (i.e. png, tif, rds). So, what I am asking... is there a way to make links to those 3 or 4 images PER file more efficiently rather than doing what I did above/below:

```
  <a href=`r test_url[1]`>Link 1 - .tif</a><br>
  <a href=`r test_url[2]`>Link 2 - .RDS</a><br>
  <a href=`r test_url[3]`>Link 3 - .png</a><br>
```

I would obviously rather not go through each and every file individually, so any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the HTML more efficient, you could generate the `<a>` tags using a for loop with a scripting language such as JavaScript or PHP.

This is an example with JS:

```js
// get the HTML elemend which has: id="directories"
var dir = document.getElementById("directories");

// generate a sample array of directories. you will need to retreive this from R
var sampleDirs = ["a.jpg","b.png","c.tif"];

// filter the array to include only png and jpg
var filteredDirs = sampleDirs.filter(x => x.includes(".png") || x.includes(".jpg"));

// loop through the filtered directories
for (var d in filteredDirs) {
  // generate a link for each directory
  dir.innerHTML = dir.innerHTML + "<a href='"+sampleDirs[d]+"'>Link "+d+" - "+sampleDirs[d]+"</a><br>";
  
}
```

```html
<html>

  <style>
 
  .myDiv {
  border: 5px outset black;
  background-color: white;    
  text-align: center;
  }
 
  </style>

  <div class="myDiv">

  <h2>Image for Date</h2>
  
  <div id="directories"></div>
 
  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar on the syntax in addition to the format on how to set up a for loop (I'm pretty new to coding). How would I set it up? And where would <a> be?

Comment: Also, how would I set up a for loop to filter out the same files and make separate links for them? Like I genuinely don't know

Comment: I've added a JavaScript demo so you get the idea of the power of for-loops

Comment: Is the top part all in <a> or would it be in the chunk as well?

Comment: I'm not following what you're trying to say. Did you 'Run code snippet'?

Comment: Yes, I did! And it is doing exactly what I intend on having my code do (with actual real links of course). I am just wondering where I would put this because you said use <a> intially.

Comment: the "<a href=`r test_url[1]`>Link 1 - .tif</a><br>" etc. which are being created manually in your example are being created procedurally in JavaScript where there's a line controlling "innerHTML"